# What do I use to manipulate text files and extract data out of it and store the output in a tabular format?

Tags: awk, sed, sh

I have a text file which has daily data for various stocks identified by PERMNO.
So the text file looks like this:

```
PERMNO = 1234

PERMNO = 2134

Market data:

    Date | Price | Return | Volume
    --------------------------------
    2019-01-01| 120 | 100 | 100

PERMNO = 3456

Market data:

    Date | Price | Return | Volume
    --------------------------------
    2019-01-01| 200 | 150 | 130
```

What I want to do is extract all the PERMNO until the market data and club it and show it with the rest of market data by adding a new column PERMNO next to rest of data. So it should look something like this:

```
Market data:

    Date | Price | Return | Volume | PERMNO
    -----------------------------------------
    2019-01-01| 120 | 100 | 100 | 1234,2134
    2019-01-01| 200 | 150 | 130 | 3456
```

I am trying to use awk for this. I am able to extract PERMNO with this, but I am unable to club it with rest of the market data by adding new column. Any alternative to awk like sed will do as well. But I am still new to shell scripts so I am not aware of their full functionalities. Can anyone suggest how should I proceed with this problem?

Comment: Can you give more info on how your script should know what the market data of PERMNO=1234 is? Is it only because no data is given that the data of the next PERMNO should be used?

Comment: Well after each list of PERMNO, there is line 'Market Data:' and then the data about those PERMNO starts from next line. after that again list of PERMNO and then again a line 'Market data:' and then data and so on. So the script should recognise if $1 == 'Market' the tabular data corresponding to PERMNO above it should start from next record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you asked for with:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=" | " }

/^PERMNO/ {
    permnos = ( permnos == "" ? "" : permnos ",") $NF
}

/^ +[[:alpha:]]/ && !doneHdr++ {
    indent = text = $0
    sub(/[^ ].*/,"",indent)
    sub(/^ +/,"",text)
    hdr = text OFS "PERMNO"
    sep = sprintf("%*s",length(hdr)+2,"")
    gsub(/ /,"-",sep)
    print "Market data:" ORS ORS indent hdr ORS indent sep
}

/^ +[0-9]/ {
    print $0, permnos
    permnos = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Market data:

    Date | Price | Return | Volume | PERMNO
    -----------------------------------------
    2019-01-01| 120 | 100 | 100 | 1234,2134
    2019-01-01| 200 | 150 | 130 | 3456
```

but I highly recommend you just generate a CSV instead for ease of further analysis/manipulation:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[ |]+"; OFS="," }

/^PERMNO/ {
    permnos = ( permnos == "" ? "" : permnos " ") $NF
}

sub(/^ +/,"") {
    $1 = $1
    if ( /^[[:alpha:]]/ && !doneHdr++ ) {
        print $0, "PERMNO"
    }
    else if ( /^[0-9]/ ) {
        print $0, permnos
        permnos = ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Date,Price,Return,Volume,PERMNO
2019-01-01,120,100,100,1234 2134
2019-01-01,200,150,130,3456
```

You can always produce a table format from that if you like using various tools, e.g. with `column`:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s, -o' | ' -t
Date       | Price | Return | Volume | PERMNO
2019-01-01 | 120   | 100    | 100    | 1234 2134
2019-01-01 | 200   | 150    | 130    | 3456
```

and if you like that line of underscores under the header:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s, -o' | ' -t | awk '1;NR==1{gsub(/./,"-");print}'
Date       | Price | Return | Volume | PERMNO
---------------------------------------------
2019-01-01 | 120   | 100    | 100    | 1234 2134
2019-01-01 | 200   | 150    | 130    | 3456
```

Comment: Thanks. The csv generation part is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give wanted output (using gawk 4.14):

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
@include "join"
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
/PERMNO/{ if(marketseen==1) {p=$3; marketseen=0} else p=p!="" ? p "," $3 : $3;  }
/Market/{ marketseen=1 }
{ split($0,a,"|");
        lc = "";
        if (a[1]~Date) lc = "PERMNO";
        if (a[1]~"0") lc = p;
        if (NF<4) lc="";
        print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4], lc }
```

input:

```
$ cat MarketData.txt
PERMNO = 1234
PERMNO = 2134
Market data:
Date | Price | Return | Volume
--------------------------------
2019-01-01| 120 | 100 | 100
PERMNO = 3456
Market data:
Date | Price | Return | Volume
--------------------------------
2019-01-01| 200 | 150 | 130
```

output:

```
$ ./marketdata.sh MarketData.txt
PERMNO = 1234
PERMNO = 2134
Market data:
Date     Price   Return          Volume PERMNO
--------------------------------
2019-01-01       120     100     100    1234,2134
PERMNO = 3456
Market data:
Date     Price   Return          Volume PERMNO
--------------------------------
2019-01-01       200     150     130    3456
```

Comment: Somehow when I run it, it prints only the last PERMNO it encounter not all PERMNO combined separated with ",". Can you explain me what does following line do p=p!="" ? p "," $3 : $3;  ?

Comment: `a?b:c` is a short notation for `if (a) { b} else {c} `

Comment: If it only print last PERMNO, it could have something to do with line-endings, the are different under Linux/windows/mac, what OS do you use? gawk likes Linux more than Windows 

Comment: it is working now. I had a typo while coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
BEGIN {FS=" = " ; H="Market data:\n\n    Date | Price | Return | Volume | PERMNO" ; print H}
/PERMNO/ {PNO = PNO "," $2 "," }
/2[0-9]{3}-/ { gsub(",,+",",",PNO) ; gsub("^,|,$","",PNO) ; print $0 " | " PNO ; PNO = ""; next}
```

1. The first line sets up the field delimiter for `PERMNO` lines, and print the header.
2. The secoind line saves (and appends) the `PERMNO` IDs (only on lines that matches `PERMNO`).
3. The third line executes when the line matches that year like pattern (this might be extended/modified), cleans up the `PNO` variable (no leading, ending or duplicate commas), then prints the whole line with the value of `PNO` appended.

It [can be seen in action at ideone](https://www.ideone.com/FDM97V).

Comment: I tried running this. It does not print any value of PNO.

Comment: It's strange. As You can see, at ideone.com it runs perfectly. What is the output then? What version of OS/AWK are You using? Oh I see, You've got an accepted answer already.